# How to get value of a Column with Remote Event Receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I created an ItemUpdating RER and I want to get the value of a column then transfer it to another column, here is my code

```
public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            // On Item Added event, the list item creation executes
            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdated)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {


                            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle);
                            ListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);

                            clientContext.Load(listItem);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                            string rawMetadata = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Source_x0020_Metadata"].ToString();                               


                            listItem["Console"] = rawMetadata ;
                            listItem.Update();
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
    if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdating)
    {
        result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("<column>", "<new value>");
        result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
    }
    return result;
}
```